# why the below code does not show error while passing by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

In the main function I created a local variable `x` . then passed it by reference to fun function . where the function declaration is  `int fun(int &x);`
but I am not understanding how the local variable is passing to fun function. 
if it would int `&x=x` where first x is the formal parameter and second `x` is the local variable . though the statement  int `&x=x` shows error in a function .but why this is not showing any error or warning here. if anybody could not understand my question. plz give me details on how a reference variable would pass in a function. another thing I want to add is this. if a reference variable would been created in the memory

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int &x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    cout << fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're just confusing references with pointers. If your function was declared as `int fun(int* x)` you would have a point.

Answer (score 1):

Your function reads `x` by `&` and returns a copy of its value so nothing wrong with it